# Перечислитель и возвращаемый тип LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Господа, есть два кусочка кода:

```
int[] nums = { 1, -2, 3, 0, -4, 5 };
```

и

```
var posNums = from n in nums
                  where n > 0
                  select n;
```

Собственно, вопрос у меня  такой: я не могу понять, какой тип данных получается у переменной posNums. Вначале я решил, что возвращается коллекция, но понял, что это не так. Выходит, что возвращается перечислитель. Однако, насколько я понимаю, то перечислитель занимается "перечислением" набора данных в определенном классе, который содержит эти данные, то есть коллекции или массиве. Тогда в связи с этим возникает вопрос, данный LINQ запрос возвращает определенный класс или что он вообще возвращает? При использовании GetType() я получаю, wherearrayiterator, но что это значит, я не пойму, и гугл тоже. Просветите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: >Вначале, я решил, что возвращается коллекция, но понял, что это не так

на основании чего вы это поняли?

Comment: Так как в любой литературе, говорится, что возвращается перечислитель. Но перечислитель это лишь метод, поэтому он не может возвращаться. А значит возвращается класс, который содержит данные + перечислитель

Comment: >Так как в любой литературе, говорится, что возвращается перечислитель

@polyakov_s покажите тогда, где и в какой литературе это говорится (желательно если этой "любой литературой" будет не вечно приводимый вами в пример косноязычный  Шилдт с отвратительным переводом, а что-то поадекватнее). В частности, в msdn русским по белому пишется, что возвращаемым значением у метода Where является IEnumerable<T>, никаких перечислителей

Comment: Вот например https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx
На счет Шилдта - 100 %

Comment: @polyakov_s 

я вижу в приведенном вами примере следующее: 

>IEnumerable<T> предоставляет перечислитель

как видите, тут нигде не сказано, что этот интерфейс **является** перечислителем. Здесь говорится, что он этот перечислитель **предоставляет**. Это разные вещи

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы забиваете себе голову какими-то совершенно ненужными деталями. При работе с Linq важно понять - все эти страшно называющиеся типы данных вам **абсолютно не нужны**. Вам нужен только один тип данных (точнее интерфейс) - это **IEnumerable<T>**. Ничего другого (с некоторыми оговорками, в частности IQueriable) о типах в Linq знать не нужно. При рабте с linq вы должны знать, что такое IEnumerable, а именно что это некая последовательность, о которой мы лишь знаем, из элементов какого типа она состоит. В том числе мы не знаем ничего о ее длине (это намек на то, что  непосредственно у IEnumerable нет метода Count, и вызов его влечет за собой перечисление коллекции), мы не можем в нее добавлять или удалять из нее элементы, но мы знаем очень важную вещь - все операции в linq оперируют с этим интерфейсом. 
(также стоит отметить, что у этого интерфейса есть две важных особенности - опасность многократного перечисления и "ленивые" вычисления, о которых нужно говорить отдельно)

Никогда программист, работая с linq, не пишет что-то типа

```
WhereArrayIterator foo = from ...
```

Он напишет

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foo = from ...
```

а еще лучше

```
var foo = from ...
```

поскольку тип данных тут имеет весьма посредственную роль (а иногда его и вовсе невозможно вывести в compile-time)

Comment: Спасибо.Я вот не пойму - да, действительно, вы правы, что возвращает некий объект,  реализованным GetEnumerator(). Но в случае первого куска кода, помимо этого в этом возвращенном объекте должны быть все значения полученные из массива по Linq-запросу. И моя неразбериха состоит в том,что каким образом возвращаемый тип методом  GetEnumerator() (а именно IEnumerator состоящий из 3 методов) получает доступ к содержимому извлеченному из массива путем этого LINQ запроса. Ведь в этом объекте реализован лишь IEnumerable , а не IEnumerator. То есть я не пойму как foreach читает данные из этого объекта

Comment: @polyakov_s есть такой умный чувак, Сергей Тепляков (у него есть очень хороший блог, в котором он пишет любопытные статьи по C#). Так вот процитирую одну из его статей: 

"Для того чтобы конструкция foreach успешно компилировалась необходимо, чтобы у объекта был метод GetEnumerator(), который вернет объект с методом MoveNext() и свойством Current, а если такого метода нет, то тогда будем искать интерфейсы IEnumerable и IEnumerable<T>"

Comment: О, спасибо за умного чувака. Интересный блог. И вам отдельное спасибо, что не послали меня еще далеко из-за моих, иногда, ненормальных вопросов.

Answer (score 7):

Какой именно тип возвращается, не так уж важно, тем более, что никакой конкретный тип не гарантирован. Хуже того, этот тип имеет право меняться при изменении типа коллекции `nums`. И конечно может меняться со сменой настроек оптимизации, выходом следующей версии компилятора или инсталляцией сервис-пака на машине клиента.

Единственное, что гарантировано — это что возвращаемый тип поддерживает интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`. Также, если я не ошибаюсь, гарантировано, что доступа к `nums` не будет до момента фактического перечисления (то, что называется lazy evaluation), поэтому такой код:

```
int nums[] = { 1, -2, 3, 0, -4, 5 };
var posNums = from n in nums
              where n > 0
              select n;
nums[0] = -1;
Console.WriteLine(posNums.First());
```

выведет 3, а не 1.

---

`wherearrayiterator` — это внутренняя подробность текущей имплементации. Не стоит полагаться на неё.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !!!

Comment: @polyakov_s: Пожалуйста!